# Moongo db aggregation in embeded document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i'am working on aggregating some data from mongodb et here is an exemple document from my collection :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("573dd055f32d05411462894e"),
"metadata" : {
    "ip" : "105.12.84.26",
    "yearmonthday" : "20160519",
    "hour" : 14,
    "month" : 5,
    "day" : 19,
    "yearmonth" : "201605",
    "minute" : 41,
    "year" : 2016
},
"new" : {
    "minutes" : {
        "40" : 1
    },
    "hourly" : {
        "14" : 1
    }
},
"minute" : {
    "14" : {
        "40" : 3,
        "41" : 7
    }
},
"hourly" : {
    "14" : 10
}
```

}

this collection is recolting the ip address then store then, new is thehour et minute an ip address request the site for the firste time.

I want my result to respond to this : in an interval of time (between hour "X" and hour "Y"), how much the same ip adress connected to my site ?

can onyone help ? thx

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i changed my data model to a simpler one like this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("573ee726f32d054114648cdb"),
"day" : 20,
"minute" : 29,
"ip" : "197.48.5.8",
"yearmonthday" : "20160520",
"hour" : 10,
"month" : 5,
"year" : 2016
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("573ee72cf32d054114648cff"),
"day" : 20,
"minute" : 30,
"ip" : "197.48.5.8",
"yearmonthday" : "20160520",
"hour" : 10,
"month" : 5,
"year" : 2016
}
```

so that a can easily aggregate ip connection based on time range.